# MySqlCommand().ExecuteReader().GetString() does not work

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm working with MySql in C# language.
I'm trying get some data out of my database. 
The fields are organized like:

```
foo baa 
38737 22222
```

I need to get value of `foo` if  my hash is equal to `baa` 
I tried this: 
My code(not working)

```
 MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=test;Uid=user;Pwd=pass;");
 con.Open();
 MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
 cmd.CommandText = string.Format("SELECT * FROM info WHERE baa = '{0}'", Hash); ;
 cmd.Connection = con;
 MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
String res = reader.GetString(0);
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Invalid attempt to access a field before calling Read()
```

Can someone point out my error?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Should also point out that this method exposes you to SQL injection attacks. See little bobby tables about this.

Comment: hash is not an input from user

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are missing a `reader.Read()` call:

```
 MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
 while(reader.Read())
 {
     String res = reader.GetString(0); 
     //...
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
string res;
using(MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    if(reader.Read())
        res = reader.GetString(0);
    else
        res = "not found";
}
```

If you change the SQL command to return a single value, for example:

```
"SELECT foo FROM info WHERE baa = '{0}' LIMIT 1"
```

then you can also use `cmd.ExecuteScalar()`:

```
string res = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```