# Binding combobox in datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf

xaml:

```
<ComboBox SelectionChanged="status_SelectionChanged" Height="23" Name="status" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Width="120">
</ComboBox>
```

how can i add the items from the database as the ItemsSource of my combobox?

```
MySqlCommand status_db = new MySqlCommand("select name from request_status", conn);
```

so:

```
List<string> combolist = new List<string>();
            MySqlDataReader reader = status_db.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                combolist.Add((string)reader);
            }
```

but is wrong...

Answer (score 0):

Its better that you fill a list with your items for example `List<request_status> myList` from your database and then set `myList` as your ItemsSource

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=myList}"
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you have the Binding in your ComboBox `ItemsSource="{Binding}"` means you need to set the DataContext of the ComboBox to the list from the SQl query :

```
MySqlCommand status_db = new MySqlCommand("select name from request_status", conn);
// build a list from the query
ObservableCollection<YourType> listElements = From_SQL_QUeury;
ComboOne.DataContext = listElements; // add x:Name="ComboOne" in the XAML for your comboxBox.
```

Comment: `build a list from the query` how?

Comment: Well this is a SQL question not a WPF one :)  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7061329/mysqlcommand-executereader-getstring-does-not-work. check more stuff on how to use MySqlCommand

Comment: Is the combolist empty? did you set it as a dataContext as I described?

Comment: combolist is not empty, if i set х: Name = "ComboOne" in xaml then name "ComboOne" is not visible...

Comment: Well teh ComboOne is just to be able to access the comboBox from behind and set the DataContext.

Answer (score 0):

Using the code you already shown to us, remove the `ItemsSource={Binding}` part from your combo box xaml.

Then just add:

```
status.ItemsSource = comboList;
```

I think this is enough to do the work for you but you have to consider using xaml bindings. But this is another big story...

Comment: i set `<ComboBox x:Name="comboitem"...` but this name is not visible

Comment: In your original code you named you combo box status and your list comboList. And that is what I used. What do you mean not visible? If your code is in your window's code there is no problem.